# Is there a way to apply a generic path for router.url?

Tags: html, angular

I have a component I use on every page of my site, and depending on the page the component shows some different information. This is fine for all of my fixed URLs as a simple ngIf takes care of each page. However, I also have an infinite number of pages possible based on an ID number of events made. Is there a way to check ngIf up to a certain URL, and then apply some generic "if theres anything after this part in the URL, do this"?

Here is what I'm doing for my fixed pages:

```
<div id="routing-wrapper" *ngIf="router.url == '/events'">
            <hr id="line">
            <span class="gray-text">Home / </span>
            <span class="gold-text">Events</span
</div>
```

Here is a sort of example of my issue:

```
<div id="routing-wrapper" *ngIf="router.url == '/events/263'">
            <hr id="line">
            <span class="gray-text">Home / Events / </span>
            <span class="gold-text">it works</span>
</div>
```

I could have any number following '/events/#', so I obviously can't hardcode every number in a ngIf.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Location service do be able what are you trying to do:
[Angular location service](https://angular.io/api/common/Location)

Try out:

```
<div id="routing-wrapper" *ngIf="location.path().match(/^\/events\/(\d+)/)">
        <hr id="line">
        <span class="gray-text">Home / Events / </span>
        <span class="gold-text">it works</span>
</div>
```

Without forgetting to add Location in the constructor:

```
constructor(private location: Location) { }
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue of checking for ANY number after '/events/' in the path.

Comment: Once you have the path thanks to Javascript String api `.match(/^\/events\/(\d+)/)` should do it

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a much simpler solution than I expected.

```
<div id="routing-wrapper" *ngIf="router.url.startsWith('/events/')">
            <hr id="line">
            <span class="gray-text">Home / Events / </span>
            <span class="gold-text">it works</span>
</div>
```